# Direct path to migrate VMWare Workstation Pro VM to Azure?

Tags: vmware-workstation, azure

Short and sweet:  I'm trying to get a definitive Yes or No, whether there's a way to *directly* migrate a VMWare Workstation Pro VM (e.g. as an OVF export), to Microsoft Azure.

I've checked the MS documentation:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-vmware/introduction

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/migrate/migrate-support-matrix-vmware-migration

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/migrate/how-to-set-up-appliance-vmware

...and it all presumes you're using VMWare vCenter & vSphere, not Workstation Pro.  This tells me the answer is probably a No, but I want to be sure before I give up on Azure being an option for re-hosting any of our Workstation Pro VMs.